# Detect if the user got to the current route by using history.goBack()

Tags: reactjs

I have an application that has a list of employees as a part of it. When the user clicks on an employee, the app navigates to the details page of the employee. In the details page there is a button that executes `history.goBack()`, which would take the user to the employee list, but that is not the only way to navigate to the employee list in the app.

I need to execute certain logic only when the user has gotten to the employee list by using `history.goBack` (the logic should NOT be executed, when the user gets to the employee list, f.e. using `history.push`).

How can I detect whether the user got there by using history.goBack() in the employee list component?

Comment: It looks like [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History) does not allow access to previously visited pages for security reason. The only option I can think of is to change the button that does `history.goBack()` to a link with special query param (like `/employees/list?returning=true`) and trigger needed logic by `returning=true` query param. You can then replace current URL via History API to get rid of the `?returning=true` query param.

Comment: You can also use cookies/localStorage/sessionStorage to store a flag when the button is clicked and logic needs to be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you also need to run this logic when the user clicks the built in browser "back" button, since this is functionally identical? The short answer is, you can't. The browser has no built in events for navigation direction by design for security reasons.

What you can do instead is create a HOC or Hook which calls `history.listen` and continuously updates some piece of state with the previous location. Then provide it as Context to the relevant components and compare it where needed with the current location.

This is probably a better solution anyway since it sounds like you only want to run logic in this limited routing scenario, and listening to a generalised "back" event would make it prone to errors should you add more ways to route back to the Employee List in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `history.action` prop. After `goBack` is `POP` while after replace is `PUSH` or `REPLACE`.

https://reactrouter.com/web/api/history

Notice that the `action` is also `POP` on first load. If you want to ignore this case, combine it with `history.length > 1`.

To summarize:

```js
const isBack = history.action === "POP" && history.length > 1;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-dom-identify-goback-1po29?file=/src/pages/Project.js
(Click on "About" and "Back")

Comment: This doesn't work because forward navigation is also a `POP` state change.

Comment: history.length can be > 1 on page reload as well.

Comment: How? Afaik, the history stack starts on reload.